# Is the template instantiation of a subclass polymorphic with a specialization of an interface

Tags: c++, polymorphism, crtp, dynamic-cast

I know this is a really confusing way to ask the question, so let me explain what I'm getting at. I have an interface that's very simple.

for the sake of argument, let's pretend it looks like:

```
class Interface 
{
    public:
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual someMethod() = 0;
};
```

And I have a class that is either a mixin, decorator, or CRTP, but I'm not sure what terminology applies

```
template< typename interface_t > 
class Disablable: public interface_t
{
    public:
    ~Disablable() override = default;
    setDisable(const bool shouldDisable) { mDisabled = shouldDisable; }

    someMethod() override 
    {
        if(mDisabled) return;
        interface_t::someMethod();
    }

    private:
    bool mDisabled = true;
};
```

My question is how polymorphism interacts with this decorator. Suppose I want to dynamically cast from an `Interface` to a `Disablable<Interface>`, will my concrete instantiations *be* a `Disablable<Interface>`?

For example, suppose I have an implementation

```
class ConcreteImplementation: public Interface
{
    void someMethod() override 
    {
        std::cout << "I printed to cout" << std::endl; 
    }
};
```

And somewhere else in code I instantiate a disablable, thusly,

```
std::unique_ptr<Interface> pInterface(new Disablable<ConcreteImplementation>());
```

Is there any way to interperet `pInterface` as `Disablable`?

Basically, is this true: 
`dynamic_cast<Disablable<Interface>>(new Disablable<ConcreteImplementation>) != nullptr`?

Asked another way, if `Derived` *is a* `Base`, is a `Decorated<Derived>` a `Decorated<Base>`?

Comment: I don't see you derive anything from anything in the code up there. Is there something missing from your example?

Comment: Well, `Disposable` is a decorator. If it was the CRTP, the base-class would know about the derived class through a template-parameter, instead of the derived deriving from a emplate-parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I want to dynamically cast from an `Interface` to a `Disablable<Interface>`, will my concrete instantiations be a `Disablable<Interface>`?

Your `Disablable<T>` derives from `T`. So if you have a pointer or reference to the `Interface` subobject of a `Disablable<Interface>` object, then you can cast this `Interface` pointer or reference to a pointer or reference to the `Disablable<Interface>` instance. This only works, of course, if your `Interface` pointer or reference does *really* refer to the `Interface` subobject of a `Disablable<Interface>`.

> Basically, is this true: 
>   `dynamic_cast<Disablable<Interface>>(new Disablable<ConcreteImplementation>) != nullptr`?

No. `ConcreteImplementation` derives from `Interface`, not from `Disablable<Interface>`. `Disablable<ConcreteImplementation>` derives from `ConcreteImplementation`, which derives from `Interface`, not from `Disablable<Interface>`.

> Asked another way, if `Derived` *is a* `Base`, is a `Decorated<Derived>` a `Decorated<Base>`?

No. Assuming that `Decorated<T>` derives from `T`, then a `Decorated<Base>` derives from `Base`. So a `Decorated<Base>` *is* a `Base`. A `Decorated<Derived>` will be a `Derived`, which *is* also a `Base`, but *not* a `Decorated<Base>`.

There is no special relationship or interaction between templates and runtime polymorphism. A class template is a template from which class types can be instantiated. A class template can be a template for a polymorphic class type. So instances of a class template can be polymorphic types. But that doesn't change anything about the fact that different instances of the same class template are unrelated types. If `Blub` is a class template, there is generally no *is-a* relationship between a `Blub<A>` and a `Blub<B>`, even if there was one between `A` and `B`. All that happens when `Blub<A>` is instantiated is that the type `A` is substituted into the definition of `Blub`. The result of that is nothing else than what you would have gotten if you had just written a new class with a corresponding definition yourself.

Apart from all that, it should probably be noted that if you find yourself wanting to perform a downcast, i.e., cast from a base pointer to a pointer to a more derived type, that should generally be taken as a clue that there [may be something not optimal about the overall design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)…

Comment: Ahhh, you're right! I'm sorry, my example didn't include inheritance in the Disablable (that's what makes it CRTP, right?). I've edited my question with that change (sorry)